# How can I work with HTML5 and CSS3 on Sublime Text 3?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3

This might be a stupid question, but I just started to learn coding and I am trying to wrap my head around these editors... but I just can not seem to work with HTML5 and CSS3 on ST3.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site, where we give step-by-step instructions on how to use software, nor is it a place where we'll teach you HTML and CSS. It is for **programming**-related questions. Please read through the entire [help] and take the [tour] to learn more about the site and what is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) for turning Sublime Text into a powerful editor.

If you have a specific use case for editing HTML and CSS files, please comment.

Syntax highlighting does come built in and you can change that in the lower right hand corner of the editor window.

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried. Do you know how to restart Sublime Text? I know this might sound really stupi and probably is but.. I just dont know how to restart it?

Comment: @ArianitHaxha quit the program and re-open it. That should be all that is required. Let me know if that doesn't work

Comment: it says:
"plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted. "
I pressed Exit. is that the way I should do it or no?

Comment: Give it a try. That should work. Let me know the result!

Comment: Ben, no, its still not working. Dont know why ,,,

Comment: You can try uninstalling the app and reinstalling it. Sublime requires Python to be installed, so it may be easier to go with a editor like Brackets.io - I hope that helps

Comment: My pleasure. Please select my response as the correct answer so it is brought to the top of the page and available for others to see!

Answer (score 0):

HTML files are just text files with a .html file extension. CSS files are text files with a .css extension. You can open any of these files in any good text editor.

Sublime Text has code syntax highlighting abilities which make it easier to read the CSS and HTML code. **Syntax highlighting only work if the file that is being displayed has the correct file extension.** You can also manually override the syntax with the button in the bottom right hand corner of the window:

[image: syntax highlighter settings]

There are also many plugins for Sublime Text which help developers create and edit HTML/CSS files. A quick [Google search](http://goo.gl/7RkYzL) will give you some good plugins to help you get started.

**UPDATE 1:** To be able to see file name extensions in Windows Explorer/File Explorer, follow [this tutorial from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions).

Comment: But the editor isn't recognizing HTML5 and CSS3 tags?

Comment: @ArianitHaxha see my latest updates.